# Layer Weight vs Geometry Node setup

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

When studying set-ups for cycles materials I encounter a frequent use of Layer Weight node and also the use of the Geometry Node. As I have difficulty to understand those set-ups I have made two very simple setups for this post.

First the Layer Weight node set-up ...
[image]
And this is the result 
[image]

Then a set-up with Geometry Node ...
[image]
With this result ...
[image]

Although I can see some differences I don't understand why artists sometimes seem to use layer weight and sometimes the Geometry set-up. What is the essential difference in the two set-ups ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example the difference between the two is caused by the multiply node. If you use an invert node instead, they are identical:

[image]

I don't think there's really any reason to use one over the other, but of course with the layer weight node it takes less time to set up.

Comment: if I add an Invert node there is a factor (standard 1.0) in it. when I reduce the value to 0.0 the geometry and layer weight set-up are the same. Are we talking about the same Invert Node ?

Comment: @JanScherders Odd.. I used a color > invert node (by default it has a factor setting, but I hid it with Ctrl H). For me, using the value output straight from the dot product node gives the inverse of the layer weight node (white on facing areas and black on glancing angles)